# How to assign ViewGroup to another ViewGroup during runtime

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a viewGroup, named Customview. I need to assign another viewGroup with multiple children to the Customview during runtime.
If above one is possible, I am not getting  the child of the viewGroup properly?

Comment: internal class CustomView:ViewGroup
    {   
  internal customView(Context context):base(context)
 {
  

 }

   }

Answer (score 0):

There is a method of `ViewGroup` called `addView()`. You can try this to add views dynamically

```
viewGroup.addView(anotherViewOrViewGroup)
```

Comment: But Not getting the child of anotherViewGroup.

Comment: You can get through id

Comment: I used to get the ViewGroup Using API , AddCustomView(ViewGroup v, Rect Bounds);